# Capture Windows Updates in a .wim so that it can be redeployed

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, deployment, wds

I am researching a new workstation deployment strategy for my company. As it stands right now we are building every workstation by hand and this takes massive amounts of time. The step that takes absolutely the longest is Windows Updates.

I currently have setup a Windows Deployment Server for testing and I have tried the following two methods to try to create a .wim that contains the latest windows updates.

**Method 1:**

I built a workstation from scratch and installed all of the necessary applications and made sure it was fully up to date. I then booted the reference workstation with Windows PE and captured an image of the workstation using the `wdscapture.exe` tool.

I then did a test deployment to a target workstation and it successfully installed. The only issue though is that none of the updates from the reference workstation seem to carry over. When I check Windows Updates on the target workstation it said I have over 100 updates.

While I realize this method is not hardware agnostic I am OK with managing a .wim file for each model workstation that belongs to our company. This is irrelevant though because Windows Updates seem to not be captured.

**Method 2:**

I attempted to follow this [guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/b9beedf4-337b-4ba3-90ab-7b8910404575/) to inject the Windows Update packages directly in the generic `install.wim` that comes on the Windows 7 DVD.

I then deployed this `install.wim` to my target workstation but I still have around 60 updates when I check Windows Updates. However the update packages that the wsusoffline tool downloads are included in the capture. So it seems to me that wsusoffline tool is not downloading all of the windows updates that are available.

**Problem:**

How can I deploy/capture a .wim with the latest Windows Updates included? Is this even possible?

Comment: the following works quite nicely http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/839ee6f0-196f-4ed7-ac55-8e753c5d5ebe/

Comment: did you get a chance to look at the script in the gallery it will work correctly and is hardware agnostic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  I'm not sure why you were unable to capture the updates.  Our image creation process is done on virtual machines as WDS / MDT images are hardware independent (drivers injected on the fly etc).  Create a hyper-v server and build your base images on that, then use Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)'s image capture task sequence and it should capture updates.  I think it would be much easier if you integrated MDT with your WDS server.  MDT helps automated image building and provides great logging for all that is occurring.

Also if you use MDT, you can add a task sequence to your build task that runs windows updates during the OS install. All automated.  If you need help with MDT watch all parts of this guy's youtube series: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aV_BgBXp47k&list=UUW9K5NBLKkxEK0kKMSTbgGQ&index=5&feature=plcp

Comment: This is what I did for method 1 above. I however did not use MDT to capture the image. I will try it today let you know.

Comment: The trick is to capture the image using MDT. This captured all of the updates and all of the software installed. Also capturing is a bit of a confusing process so here is a link for the process using MDT 2010 for future reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-run-a-sysprep-and-capture-task-sequence-from-mdt-2010.aspx . Thanks for your help!